# Why do you have to wrap parenthesis around a number to called toFixed on it?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
1.toFixed(2) // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

(1).toFixed(2) // "1.00"

let num = 1
num.toFixed(2) // "1.00"
```

At the same time, you don't have to wrap parenthesis around strings to call methods on them

```
'yo'.repeat(3) // "yoyoyo"
```

What is the rule at play here and where else does it apply? Guessing it has something to do with the dot being misinterpreted as a decimal for numbers?

Comment: An number looks like some digits optionally followed by `.` and more digits. That's what the parser assumes the `.` means here. It's not being *mis*interpreted; the token syntax for numbers takes precedence over the language grammar.

Comment: Try `1..toFixed(2)` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Nice trick. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because the interpreter is looking for more digits (decimal values), not keywords or methods.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, JavaScript is looking for more numbers after the decimal point.  It thinks you are trying to type a float like `1.2` and it doesn't like that `t` there, it's not a number.

Interestingly, you can do this without parenthesis or making variable by using 2 decimal points.  Like this: `1..toFixed(2)`.  I guess you can also do `1.0.toFixed(2)` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

- When using a variable, Javascript is confident that you're not going to add decimals after the point.
- When not using a variable, Javascript thinks that you are going to add decimals after the point.
- When you wrap your number with parenthesis, you say that the number is finished, and everything is fine again.
- You can also use `..` if you don't like parenthesis. The first one for decimals, the second one to call the method.

```js
let num = 1;
console.log(num.toFixed(2));

// console.log(1.toFixed(2)); // ERROR

console.log((1).toFixed(2));

console.log(1..toFixed(2));
```