# 5.constructor.name - SyntaxError

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't it work when I write like this

```
console.log(5.constructor.name)?
```

But if I write this:

```
const num = 5;
console.log(num.constructor.name);// Number
```

or that, then everything works.

```
console.log(0.5.constructor.name);// Number
```

```
const num = 5;
console.log(num.constructor.name);// Number
console.log(0.5.constructor.name);// Number
console.log(5.constructor.name); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: Try `(5).constructor.name`. The `.` is being interpreted by the parser as a decimal point, not as the `.` for object references.

Comment: because parser expects a number after the first decimal...

Comment: The JavaScript parser will think that you are writing a decimal number. On the other hand, when writing 0.5.constructor the meaning of the `.` is unambiguous

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504115/why-do-you-have-to-wrap-parenthesis-around-a-number-to-called-tofixed-on-it

Comment: When you say  "*everything works*" do you mean that you are just not getting errors or you are actually getting the desired result?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you all very much for the explanation.